# Change in touch device architecture in windows 8

Tags: windows-7, driver, windows-8, wdk

Has anything changed in the touch device architecture in windows 8?, I have a driver which i wrote and compiled using driver kit 7 will it work in windows it if i will try to install it . Or if it will not then will i be able compile it using windows driver kit 8 ?

Comment: I don't know the specific answer, but there are 20+ sessions at Build tagged with "driver".  You might find your answer there. http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011?sort=sequential&direction=desc&term=&t=drivers

Comment: I can't watch all the sessions , i watched a few but i couldn't find the answer.